# Update database using stored procedure in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I try to update my database with ASP.NET. I have a button, when I click it, the code should save data using the stored procedure I wrote; however, when I click on it, it does not save anything.

Mycode.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand update_item = new SqlCommand("UsuariosSistemaUpdate", con))
        {
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@ControlError", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@UsuariosSistemaID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox5.Text;
           update_item.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Administrador", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(CheckBox1.Checked);
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Almacen", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(CheckBox2.Checked);
            update_item.Parameters.Add("@Activo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(CheckBox3.Checked);
            update_item.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            update_item.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UsuariosSistemaUpdate]
    @ControlError      VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT,
    @UsuariosSistemaID INT,
    @Nombre            VARCHAR(100),
    @Usuario           VARCHAR(15),
    @Password          VARCHAR(15),
    @Administrador     BIT,
    @Email             VARCHAR(50),
    @Almacen           BIT,
    @Activo            BIT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        SET @ControlError = '';

        UPDATE [dbo].[UsuariosSistema]
        SET [Nombre] = @Nombre,
            [Usuario] = @Usuario,
            [Password] = @Password,
            [Administrador] = @Administrador,
            [Email] = @Email,
            [Almacen] = @Almacen,
            [Activo] = @Activo
        WHERE 
            UsuariosSistemaID = @UsuariosSistemaID
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ControlError = ERROR_MESSAGE(); 

        INSERT INTO LogErrores (Numero, Mensaje, Procedimiento, Linea) 
        VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE())
    END CATCH;
END
```

I need some help here, when I click in button, nothing happen, Who knows why? I'm new to using stored procedures in ASP.NET

Comment: Did you debug to make sure the ID coming from Textbox5.Text is right for parameter UsuariosSistemaID ?  Does that number match a record in your table?  Is there any error logged in SQL table LogErrores?

Comment: What is the Error that you are getting?

Comment: The question says, "I have an error." Does that mean that your code is throwing some exception? If so, what is it? I don't think you need to convert `Checkbox.Checked` to a `byte`. `Checked` is a `bool`, and it will be correctly converted to a `bit`. Are there any errors in the log table? Can you set a breakpoint and make sure this code is getting called?

Comment: In my database called "System Users" it does not update through my Stored Procedure, when I click, it should be updated when performing said action, but nothing is updated, I wanted to know if I am failing here. 
Yes, I change the value for bool, Check my code again.

Comment: @EduardoLeon Add  `update_item.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` before you give your parameters and please show the error that you are getting.

Comment: I try it, but still dont working, SORRY, I see put the word "ERROR" but is because my code doesn't work. sorry, im newbie in this.

Comment: @EduardoLeon Surround your `using` statement with `try-catch` block and then you would be able to see what exception you are getting.

Comment: First set output parameter direction, default is input `var prm = update_item.Parameters.Add("@ControlError", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: As Rahul mentioned, Commantype before parameters. Then open your connection, execute then close connection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/yy6y35y8(v=vs.71)

Comment: Nope, I see in my code, this sound like a joke, but, I forgot to put the "On Click" in the button. `<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Actualizar Usuarios" class="btn btn-primary botoninfo" onclick="Button2_Click"/>`, after that, all working like a charm.

Comment: @EduardoLeon That's why it's so important to create a [MCVE]. The simple act of doing so often helps you find these issues quickly.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, thanks @mason